# std::invoke_result_t invocation generates a compiler error that no type is defined on std::invoke_result

Tags: c++, c++17

I've written a class template that has a vector of Callables (which is meant to allow the client to register a list of callbacks) and have defined a function `call()` which calls all the callbacks with some special casing for callbacks that have a return value and for those that don't. However I'm getting a `no type named 'type' in 'std::invoke_result` compiler error.
I was wondering if someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong.

```cpp
template<typename Callable, typename... Args>
class CallbackList : public ACancelable {
public:
  CallbackList() = default;
  ~CallbackList() override = default;
  decltype(auto) call(Args&&... args) {
    decltype(mCallbacks) copyOfCallbacks{};
    {
      std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk{mMtx};
      copyOfCallbacks = mCallbacks;
    }
    if constexpr(std::is_same_v<std::invoke_result_t<Callable, Args...>, void>){
      for(auto &pair : copyOfCallbacks) {
        std::invoke(std::forward<Callable>(pair.first), std::forward(args)...);
      }
      return;
    } else {
      std::vector<std::invoke_result_t<Callable, Args...>> results;
      for(auto &pair : copyOfCallbacks) {

        results.push_back(std::invoke(std::forward<Callable>(pair.first), std::forward(args)...));
      }
      return results;
    }
  }
  std::weak_ptr<ACancelableToken> registerCallback(Callable&& fn) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk{mMtx};
    auto token = std::make_shared<utils::ACancelableTokenImpl>(
        dynamic_cast<ACancelable &>(*this)
    );
    mCallbacks.push_back(std::make_pair(std::move(fn), token));
    return token;
  }

  void CancelWith(std::shared_ptr<ACancelableToken> spToken) override {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk{mMtx};
    auto lastIt = std::remove_if(
        mCallbacks.begin(),
        mCallbacks.end(),
        [this, spToken](auto &p) {
          return (spToken == p.second);
        }
    );
    mCallbacks.erase(lastIt, mCallbacks.end());
  }

private:
  std::vector<std::pair<Callable, std::shared_ptr<ACancelableToken>>> mCallbacks;
  std::mutex mMtx;
};
```

The following is the unit test that I've written where I'm seeing the error.

```cpp
TEST(CallbackListTest, CanRegisterACallback) {
  using Callback = std::function<void(int, float, std::string)>;
  CallbackList<Callback> testable;
  size_t callbackCount{};
  int a = 1;
  float b = 2.0;
  std::string str{"Test String"};

  testable.registerCallback([&callbackCount](int a, float b, std::string str) {
    ASSERT_EQ(1, a);
    ASSERT_EQ(2.0, b);
    ASSERT_EQ("Test String", str);
    callbackCount++;
  });
  testable.call(a, b, str);
}
```

The line `testable.call(a, b, str);` is reporting

```
In template: no type named 'type' in 'std::invoke_result<std::function<void (int, float, std::basic_string<char>)>>'
```

and pointing to the line in `call` function

```cpp
if constexpr(std::is_same_v<std::invoke_result_t<Callable, Args...>, void>){
```

Any help would be appreciated.
I've tried just writing a test with the following and I'm not seeing any errors

```cpp
TEST(CallbackListTest, StaticAssertCheck){
  using Callback = std::function<void(int, float, std::string)>;
  static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::invoke_result_t<Callback, int, float, std::string>, void> == true);
}
```

**EDIT**

I tried switching my implementation to specify the Return type as a template parameter and used a `std::function` in my callback container, however I'm running into a compiler error that I'm not able to understand and that I can't see in the compiler explorer link provided by @Aconcagua.

This is my updated code.

```cpp
template<typename Return, typename... Args>
class CallbackList : public ACancelable {
public:
  CallbackList() = default;
  ~CallbackList() override = default;
  decltype(auto) operator()(Args... args) {
    decltype(mCallbacks) copyOfCallbacks{};
    {
      std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk{mMtx};
      copyOfCallbacks = mCallbacks;
    }
    if constexpr(std::is_same_v<Return, void>){
      for(auto &pair : copyOfCallbacks) {
        std::invoke(std::forward<Return(Args...)>(pair.first), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
      }
      return;
    } else {
      std::vector<Return> results;
      for(auto &pair : copyOfCallbacks) {

        results.push_back(std::invoke(std::forward<Return(Args...)>(pair.first), std::forward<Args>(args)...));
      }
      return results;
    }
  }
  template <typename Callable>
  std::weak_ptr<ACancelableToken> registerCallback(Callable&& fn) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk{mMtx};
    auto token = std::make_shared<utils::ACancelableTokenImpl>(
        static_cast<ACancelable &>(*this)
    );
    mCallbacks.emplace_back(std::move(fn),token);
    return token;
  }
  template <typename Callable>
  std::weak_ptr<ACancelableToken> registerCallback(Callable const& fn) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk{mMtx};
    auto token = std::make_shared<utils::ACancelableTokenImpl>(
        static_cast<ACancelable &>(*this)
    );
    mCallbacks.emplace_back(fn,token);
    return token;
  }

  void CancelWith(std::shared_ptr<ACancelableToken> spToken) override {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk{mMtx};
    auto lastIt = std::remove_if(
        mCallbacks.begin(),
        mCallbacks.end(),
        [this, spToken](auto &p) {
          return (spToken == p.second);
        }
    );
    mCallbacks.erase(lastIt, mCallbacks.end());
  }

private:
  std::vector<std::pair<std::function<Return(Args...)>, std::shared_ptr<ACancelableToken>>> mCallbacks;
  std::mutex mMtx;
};
```

Test Code

```cpp
TEST(CallbackListTest, CanRegisterACallback) {
  using Callback = void(int, float, std::string);
  CallbackList<Callback> testable;
  size_t callbackCount{};
  int a = 1;
  float b = 2.0;
  std::string str{"Test String"};

  testable.registerCallback([&callbackCount](int a, float b, std::string str) {
    ASSERT_EQ(1, a);
    ASSERT_EQ(2.0, b);
    ASSERT_EQ("Test String", str);
    callbackCount++;
  });
  testable(a, b, str);
  ASSERT_EQ(1, callbackCount);
}
```

And this is the compiler error

```
  In file included from /home/kartik/fun/motive_aosp/src/vg5/services/DriverMonitor/drivermonitorcpptest/src/main/cpp/src/CallbackListTest.cpp:13:
  /home/kartik/fun/motive_aosp/src/vg5/services/DriverMonitor/deps/NativeUtils/inc/nativeutils/CallbackList.hpp:77:39: error: function cannot return function type 'void (int, float, std::basic_string<char>)'
    std::vector<std::pair<std::function<Return(Args...)>, std::shared_ptr<ACancelableToken>>> mCallbacks;
                                        ^
  /home/kartik/fun/motive_aosp/src/vg5/services/DriverMonitor/drivermonitorcpptest/src/main/cpp/src/CallbackListTest.cpp:19:26: note: in instantiation of template class 'motive::utils::CallbackList<void (int, float, std::basic_string<char>)>' requested here
    CallbackList<Callback> testable;
                           ^
  1 error generated.
```

Comment: Your `CallbackList` has a `Callback` but no `Args`. `CallbackList<Callback> testable;` Since the callback is `std::function<void(int, float, std::string)`, naturally it cannot be called with an empty list of arguments.

Comment: Just as a side note: Do not compare booleans against `true` or `false`, that's not idiomatic, instead just check `if(booleanValue)` or if you need the inverse `if(!booleanValue)`.

Comment: Thank you very much folks. I should have known better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual cause is (as denoted in comments already) that you create a callback list with the `Callable` type being set, but no matching arguments added reflecting the arguments of the callback:

```
using Callback = std::function<void(int, float, std::string)>;
//CallbackList<Callback /*lacking arguments! */> testable;
// you need instead:
CallbackList<Callback, int, float, std::string)>;
```

But that's a consequence of a questionable design, introducing redundancy between the callback type and its arguments.

You avoid this problem if you specialise the callback list explicitly for callable types, similarly to what `std::function` does, too:

```
template<typename Callable>
class CallbackList; // leave unimplemented!

template<typename Return, typename... Args>
class CallbackList<Return(Args...)> : public ACancelable
//                 ^-------------^ specialised for callable types
{
public:
    // now we can append any arbitrary callable directly
    // (by moving and copying, if need be):
    template <typename Callable>
    void append(Callable&& c)
    {
        m_callbacks.emplace_back
        (
            std::move(c),
            std::make_shared<utils::ACancelableTokenImpl>
            (
                static_cast<ACancelable&>(*this)
                // static_cast is fine, we *do* know that we are
                // a ACancelable, see class definition!
                // actually we shouldn't need the cast at all
            )
        );
    }
    template <typename Callable>
    void append(Callable const& c)
    {
        m_callbacks.emplace_back
        (
            c, std::make_shared<utils::ACancelableTokenImpl>(*this)
        );
    }

private:
    // and we create the std::function objects internally,
    // they do not have to be declared outside the class any more:
    std::vector
    <
        std::pair
        <
            std::function<Return(Args...)>,
            std::shared_ptr<ACancelableToken>
            //      ^ if you don't actually share
            //        unique_ptr would be more suitable (cheaper!)
        >
    > m_callbacks;
};
```

Note: We have a *callback* list anyway, thus I consider `append` a more suitable name, but that's up to you to decide…

Yet another benefit: You don't need `std::invoke_result` any more at all, you get the return type from the template argument directly (`Return` – well, you'd need a better name yet…).

Usage mainly remains the same, but your callback declaration gets much simpler:

```
// using Callback = <whatever>; // <- now entirely obsolete
CallbackList<void(int, float, std::string)> testable;
// just as before: simply add the callback:
testable.append([](int a, float b, std::string str) { /*...*/ });
```

Note: While syntactically registering callbacks remains the same under the hoods there *is* a difference: There's no temporary `std::function` instance created *before* calling `append`/`registerCallback` any more, instead creation of has been moved *into* the function or more precisely even deeper into the `std::pair`'s constructor called from within `std::vector::emplace_back`.

Demonstration at [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/z5Gqn1WW1).

Comment: Thank you very much @Aconcagua. One of the things I noticed with `std::function` is that I can't capture move only objects. I ran into this in another class template that was running posted callbacks on thread and based on another stack overflow answer, created a callable interface and then had template class that was a derived version of the interface. Can you recommend something in order to accommodate callables that can capture move only objects?

Comment: One other question, in append, should i use a static assert to make sure Callable has the proper signature ?

Comment: @KartikAiyer The static-assert is not necessary – if signature doesn't match you'll get a compilation error anyway by `std::function`. If you're not satisfied with compiler's error message though, you might refine it that way.

Comment: About capturing objects: Well, std::function is pretty unfortunate at this point. If you do not want to *copy* the object in question then [`std::ref`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref) is your friend. If you can rely on C++23 then there's [`std::move_only_function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/move_only_function). If everything else fails you might create your own wrapper (using e.g. using a polymorphic approach), that's not too heavy.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestions @Aconcagua. I'm running into a compiler error when I use `std::function` in my container. I've added an edit to my description. I'm not able to understand that error and was wondering if you have any suggestions.

Comment: @KartikAiyer You have introduced several problems: `CallbackList<void(int, float, std::string)> testable;` – as is, this would require your callbacks return a `void(int, float, std::string)`, i.e. a function and not accepting any arguments. There are two ways to fix: Either change to `CallbackList<void, int, float, std::string> testable;` if you want to keep the simpler template class or – if you want to retain the function syntax for instantiation, *specialise* your template as [here](https://godbolt.org/z/Wb93Y3Y3f) – that's essential!

Comment: Then secondly don't apply `std::forward` – you cannot forward perfectly here anyway, your function arguments are already fixed at this place (in context of the operator). Perfect forwarding requires the function arguments being non-fixed template arguments themselves, in given case a secondary set of template parameters for the operator, as [here](https://godbolt.org/z/jx97ojxdY). More detailed explanation only focused on perfect forwarding in templates see [here](https://godbolt.org/z/YKraqjGM5).